# How do I stop all currently playing MediaElement players?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediaelement.js

I'm wondering how to stop all the MediaElement players currently in the DOM. I've tried this:

```
$('video,audio').each(function() {
      $(this)[0].player.pause();
});
```

Let me know if that works.

A quick and dirty one, but neither work.

```
$(".mejs-play").live('click',function(){
  $(".mejs-pause").trigger('click');                              
});
```

Tried to do my homework on this one but can't seem to find a response anymore.

Answer (score 10):

Try this...

```
$('video, audio').each(function() {
      $(this)[0].pause();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple way to do a "stop all".

When first creating your MediaElement players, create them each explicity (as opposed to using `$('video,audio').mediaelementplayer()`):

```
var mediaElementPlayers = [];
$('video,audio').each(function(){
    mediaElementPlayers.push(new MediaElementPlayer(this));
});
```

And then, when you want to stop them:

```
for (var i=0; i<mediaElementPlayers.length; i++){
    mediaElementPlayers[i].pause(); // pause
    if (mediaElementPlayers[i].getCurrentTime()){
        mediaElementPlayers[i].setCurrentTime(0); // rewind
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very nice @Bart

And here is an addition to Barts function to stop audio in a certain context (within a certain element). Useful to stop media playing in a popup when it is closed for example:

```
function stopAudio(context) {
    for (var i=0; i<mediaElementPlayers.length; i++){
        if($(mediaElementPlayers[i].container).parents().find(context).length === 0) {
            mediaElementPlayers[i].pause(); // pause
            if (mediaElementPlayers[i].getCurrentTime()){
                mediaElementPlayers[i].setCurrentTime(0); // rewind
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trigger the click event of pause button will work....[check it here](http://smarttips.in/category/youtube/)

```
$('.mejs-pause button').trigger("click");
```